# How do I return conditional status codes using F# syntax in WebAPI

Tags: f#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm struggling to figure out how to make the compiler happy when accounting for both happy and sad path scenarios of an ActionResult.

I thought I could do the following:

```
[<HttpGet>]
member x.GetQuery([<FromQuery>] restaurant:string) =

    restaurant 
    |> Name 
    |> Query.menu
    |> function
       | Error _ -> (x.StatusCode 500)                          :> IActionResult
       | Ok    v -> ActionResult<DataTransfer.MenuItemTypes>(v) :> IActionResult
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Error FS0193  Type constraint mismatch. The type 
>       'ActionResult'     is not compatible with type
>       'IActionResult'

I can get the code to compile if I do this:

```
[<HttpGet>]
member x.GetQuery([<FromQuery>] restaurant:string) =

    restaurant 
    |> Name 
    |> Query.menu
    |> function
       | Error _ -> failwith "Internal Server Error"
       | Ok    v -> ActionResult<DataTransfer.MenuItemTypes>(v)
```

However, I don't want to throw an exception just to return a status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the methods on the controller base class to create the return value.  You should be able to make it work in your first example by changing the `Ok` case to use the `Ok` method:

```
[<HttpGet>]
member x.GetQuery([<FromQuery>] restaurant:string) =

    restaurant 
    |> Name 
    |> Query.menu
    |> function
       | Error _ -> x.StatusCode(500) :> IActionResult
       | Ok    v -> x.Ok(v) :> IActionResult
```